# Export EC2 AMI into VMDK

Tags: amazon-ec2, vmware, ec2-ami

Am trying to export my AMI into VMDK file to use on local with VMware. looking at the doc, I only found this one:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport.html But, there restrictions.

Because the AMI was created using Ubuntu AMI from Amazon, and not uploaded
from a VMK file.

Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Out of those restrictions, which one is worrying you?

Comment: because AMI was created from Amazon AMI

Comment: Create an AMI from a running instance of the previous AMI and you should have sufficient ownership to export your own AMI.